# How can I tell which one is a superclass in UML diagram

Tags: uml

[image]

How do I find out which one's a superclass?

I think from that picture it would be `CChatWnd` because it has many arrows going to other sub-classes, but it also has an arrow going out to `CprivateChatWnd`.

Answer (score 2):

CChatWnd is a superclass of CPrivateChatWnd, and CPanelWnd is a superclass of CChatWnd.

Note that there are two types of arrows in your diagram: those between the classes I mentioned are generalisations, whilst the other ones are directed associations.

Comment: This answer is correct, so give him the answer.  The more common synonym for a Superclass is Generalisation.  So CChatWnd is a generalisation of CPrivateChatWnd, and CPanelWnd is a generalisation of CChatWnd.  Conversely CPrivateChatWnd is specialisation of CChatWnd, and CChatWnd is specialisation of CPanelWnd.

Answer (score 0):

For a quick overview of the basics of UML class diagrams I find this [link](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rational/library/content/RationalEdge/sep04/bell/) useful. For you current question the section regarding Inheritance might be of special interest.